# Can i start a iPhone app by an iframe?

Tags: iphone, iframe, ios-simulator, iphone-web-app

Id like, if possible, just create an App for iphone by and URL, like http://keepyourlinks.com/browser.php
my go it's to make a browser inside a browser....

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, our app uses a browser inside the native application to view a web site.  We also setup encryption and session variables so that we can check if they are logged in and validate that they are on the iPhone app and not in a browser.

You can use a UIWebView in your XIB and pass it a URL.